# using mysqli instead of mysql accessing the DB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
    please find below a script in php that that fetch data from my database company, the database is in phpMyadmin
```

I understand that there are secure ways to fetch data. My question is
        Can I improve the code below using mysqli to fetch instead of mysql_query.

```
    <?php 
        get results from database. Can I improve the code below using mysqli to fetch instead of mysql_query in the following line?.

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer")
                        or die(mysql_error());   
    tables begins here with the customer id and customer name
                echo "<table >"; 
                echo "<tr>              
                            <th>ID</th>   the customer id
                            <th>Name</th> the customer name
                             </tr>"; 

                // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    the table below display the columns in html using mysql fetch array. all data is displayed.

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 

                        // echo out the contents of each row into a table  
    my purpose is embed the php in html in another way using msqli 
                        echo "<tr>"; 
                        echo '<td>' . $row['CustomerID'].'</td>'; 
                        echo '<td>' . $row['Name']. '</td>'; 
                       echo "</tr>";  
                }  
                       echo "</table>"; 
        ?> 
my purpose is embed the php in html in another way using msqli
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all the `mysql` with `mysqli`

```
      $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM customer");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
```

If you wanna keep it simple

Or do it like this...

```
  /*Your connection info goes here...*/
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
    }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM customer";

  if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

   echo "<table ><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>"; 

   /* fetch results by row */
   while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    echo "<tr><td>' . $row['CustomerID'].'</td><td>' . $row['Name']. '</td></tr>'; 
   }

  /* free the result set */
  $result->close();
 }

 /* close the connection */
 $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: hi made some changes $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my database","my database");

Comment: unable to select database  <?php
//$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database','tablename');
//if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
//printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
//exit();
// }
$query = "SELECT * FROM customer where CustomerID ='1'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>"; 
/* fetch results by row */
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['CustomerID'].'</td><td>' . $row['Name']. '</td></tr>'; }
$result->close();
} $mysqli->close();?>

Comment: Well are you sure you have mysqli_* enabled, check your PHP.ini file